# Android create e timer that goes also in background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, timer, background

i need to create a timer (with start and stop function), that continue to work also in background, because:
 - my app have 2 activity switchable via intent, so if i return to activity 1 the timer must continue to work, and if i return to activity 2 (that of the timer) the "textview" must update the timer that is continuing to work
 - if i put the app in background, the timer must continue to work.
how can i do this?
i've found this, but i'm not sure that it can do what i need: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-timer-example/

Thanks!

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089815/chronometer-inside-service

Answer (score 1):

For making the timer working in background, use **Asynctask**. Then if necessary, you can switch activities in the foreground from doinBackground function of Asynctask using **RunOnUiThread** method (or separate thread if you so desire).

Answer (score 0):

Standard Java way to use timers via `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask` works fine in Android, but you should be aware that this method creates a new thread.

You may consider using the very convenient Handler class `(android.os.Handler)` and send messages to the handler via `sendMessageAtTime(android.os.Message, long)` or `sendMessageDelayed(android.os.Message, long`). Once you receive a message, you can run desired tasks. Second option would be to create a Runnable object and schedule it via Handler's functions `postAtTime(java.lang.Runnable, long)` or `postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long).`

**For a repeating task:**

new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, after, interval);
**For a single run of a task:**

new Timer().schedule(task, after);

task being the method to be executed
after the time to initial execution
(interval the time for repeating the execution)

**Handler:**

```
private final int interval = 1000; // 1 Second
private Handler handler = new Handler();
Private Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "C'Mom no hands!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
...
handler.postAtTime(runnable, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval);
handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
```

**Message:**

```
private final int EVENT1 = 1; 
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {         
        case Event1:
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Event 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        default:
            Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Unhandled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

...

```
Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(EVENT1);
handler.sendMessageAtTime(msg, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval);
handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, interval);
```